# Samba - Unable to open new log file '/var/log/samba/smbd.log': Permission denied

Tags: samba

When I check samba status it shows me the following errors:

```
service smb status

Mar 03 11:17:37 fujitsu.localdomain smbd[203323]:   Unable to open new log file '/var/log/samba/log.smbd': Permission denied
Mar 03 11:17:37 fujitsu.localdomain smbd[203323]: [2021/03/03 11:17:37.691484,  0] ../lib/util/debug.c:1055(reopen_logs_internal)
Mar 03 11:17:37 fujitsu.localdomain smbd[203323]:   Unable to open new log file '/var/log/samba/log.smbd': Permission denied
Mar 03 11:17:37 fujitsu.localdomain smbd[203323]: [2021/03/03 11:17:37.691532,  0] ../lib/util/debug.c:1055(reopen_logs_internal)
Mar 03 11:17:37 fujitsu.localdomain smbd[203323]:   Unable to open new log file '/var/log/samba/log.smbd': Permission denied
Mar 03 11:17:37 fujitsu.localdomain smbd[203323]: [2021/03/03 11:17:37.728845,  0] ../lib/util/become_daemon.c:138(daemon_ready)
Mar 03 11:17:37 fujitsu.localdomain smbd[203323]:   daemon_ready: STATUS=daemon 'smbd' finished starting up and ready to serve connections
Mar 03 11:17:37 fujitsu.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Samba SMB Daemon.
Mar 03 11:17:37 fujitsu.localdomain smbd[203323]: [2021/03/03 11:17:37.732849,  0] ../lib/util/debug.c:1055(reopen_logs_internal)
Mar 03 11:17:37 fujitsu.localdomain smbd[203323]:   Unable to open new log file '/var/log/samba/log.smbd': Permission denied
```

Otherwise status of samba is active but this error really confusing me.
I tried to change permissions for this folder but it did't help.

Comment: In case of a distro from the Redhat family, I tend to suspect SELinux when permissions should work but don't. Otherwise Apparmor. SELinux violations are logged in /var/log/audit/audit.log.